# Google Image Charts -- As SVG?

Tags: svg, google-visualization

How do I save a [Google image chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/) that I generated with a URL as an **SVG** file? Right now it's PNG.

Answer (score -1):

You need the dynamic API, not the static API.

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/choosing.html

Comment: How do I save it as SVG (programmatically)?

Comment: You can't - Google transmits it to you as a png. Look at my link above, and use the dynamic charts instead. You get those as svgs.

Comment: @user: No, I mean, how do I save the dynamic ones as SVGs (programmatically)?

Comment: Don't understand, I'm afraid. It's already an svg. How did you get a png? Are you sure you're not using the static API? What's the URL you're using?

Comment: @user785194: I haven't tried it yet -- I'm asking *about your answer*! :) You mentioned I should use the Dynamic API, but I'm asking you how I would save it as an SVG when I use it. I haven't used it yet, because I don't know how to save it as an SVG.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you don't understand. Go to the Google website, right-click their example pie chart, 'save as', and you save it as an svg file. Do you *really* want to save it "programatically"? Outside a browser? Open a socket, connect to Google, send a GET, write the returned data to a file with an .svg extension, whatever. :)

Comment: @user: Yes, I *really* need to save it programmatically... right-click-save-as doesn't work :P. The trouble is that I have no idea what the URL GET format and everything is -- the only documentation available is for the static API. What URL do I use? The only URL I know is for the static API; the dynamic API uses JavaScript, and I have no idea how to translate the result to SVG. Do you happen to know where they're documented, and how I can actually send data in the URL to the dynamic API?

Comment: Ok, we're not on the same planet. Just try it. Someone writes JS on their web page, which runs 'google.visualization'. This talks to Google. Google sends back an SVG. The SVG is displayed by the viewer's browser. The SVG is *present* in the viewer's browser. When you right-click-view-source you see *SVG* source. It's full of SVG shapes, and obfuscated JS. *Google* "translates the result to SVG" and sends it to *you*. Capiche? :)